# Style for all inputs except for ones with a specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a CSS style defined for all inputs with type text on the page. I'm using the [Spectrum Color Chooser](http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/#toc5) on part of my page, and this is implemented onto the page using

```
<input type="text" class="basic" />
```

I'm trying to override the "global" styling that I've applied to all inputs of type text using the following, but it's not working:

```
input[type=text]:not([class=basic]), select {
    height:28px;
    border:1px solid #c5d1db;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    color:#627686;
    font-size:13px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 4px 5px 0 #ebebeb;
    margin:0;
}
```

Is there a way to override this?

Comment: Place your new style after that style in the CSS sheet, make sure you override all settings you made in the first styles. CSS specificity should take care of the rest without worrying about adding custom selectors like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really fail to see the issue here, isn't this the point of CSS specificity?  http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/GBH8b/

```
input[type=text]{
height:28px;
border:1px solid #c5d1db;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
color:#627686;
font-size:13px;
box-shadow:inset 0 4px 5px 0 #ebebeb;
margin:0;
}

input[type=text].basic{
height:18px;
border:1px solid #000;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
color:#627686;
font-size:13px;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized my stupidity after I had posted it. Been staring at this stylesheet for too many days straight. This works.

Comment: lol, fair enough. Sometimes it just takes that second set of eyes, been there done that!

Comment: `input[type=text]:not(.basic)` works too... but it's easier to just override.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS code posted works, affecting fields not in the class, on supporting browsers (including modern browsers in general, but excluding IE 8 an older).

It does not affect fields that *are* in the class, obviously. But replacing an existing rule that applies to all input fields by this more restricted rule would make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Just Declare `!important` as it will override the main.

```
input[type=text]:not([class=basic]), select {
    height:28px !important;
    border:1px solid #c5d1db;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    color:#627686;
    font-size:13px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 4px 5px 0 #ebebeb;
    margin:0;
}
```